# backend: get custom options from invoice

Tags: custom-options, invoice, backend

I am working on the backend invoice template.

In adminhtml (sales/order/invoice/view/items.phtml), the item list is performed with :

```
<?php $_items = $this->getInvoice()->getAllItems() ?>
<?php $i=0;foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
    <?php echo $this->getItemExtraInfoHtml($_item->getOrderItem()) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I would like to be able to access items custom options inside that loop.

I tried several things :

```
$_item->getOptions();
$_item->getProductOptions();
$_item->getItemOptions();
$_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
```

but none is working…

Thank you for your help,

Comment: `$_item->getProductOptions()` should be the one.  What happens when you `var_dump` it? Does it return NULL?

Comment: in fact, I extended the Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Invoice/View/Items.php, with a custom function that performs $_items = $this->getInvoice()->getAllItems(); and a loop with $options = $_item->getItemOptions(); . I then try foreach ($options as $option) which returns an error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution: `$_options = $_item->getOrderItem()->getProductOptions();`